# Copy standard Odoo module to new custom module

Tags: odoo

Is there a straight forward process to copy a module to a new module name with its own dependencies?

In my example I need to create a module very similar to the EVENTS module, but I also need the EVENTS module in its original form.

I figure the easiest way is to copy the events module to a new module name and then make my changes to it.

Comment: Inherit `events` module and add your dependancies.

Comment: I am fairly fresh with Odoo Dev but if I include it as a dependency doesn't that just install it?

I need all the code from EVENTS module as a starting point for my module

Comment: What is the purpose of this module you want to change something defined in even module, you want to create another menu that have the same items as event module, why you are doing that?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do that... but you have to refactor the MODULE name, MODELS name, VIEWS(form,tree,action) name DIFFERENT from EVENT modules. So ur EVENT modules didn't get pile up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, it's a very bad idea.

## Inheritance is what you want

What you want to do is create a new module with the module `event` as a dependency of your module. Then you can create new views that inherit existing views using the this in the view definitions:

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="xml_id_of_view" />
```

Then all the model class that you need to update have to inherit the existing models as explained in [ORM Inheritance](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension). You'll have choice between 3 ways on inheritance:

> 1. creating a new model from an existing one, adding new information to the copy but leaving the original module as-is
> 2. extending models defined in other modules in-place, replacing the previous version
> 3. delegating some of the model’s fields to records it contains

```
# 1.
class Event(models.Model):
    _name = "new_event"
    _inherit = "event.event"


# 2.
class Event(models.Model):
    _inherit = "event.event"

# 3.
class Holiday(models.Model):
    _name = "event.holiday"
    _inherits = {
       "event.event": "event_id"
    }
    event_id = fields.Many2one("event.event")
```

I won't go into details on the 3 possible ways on inheritance to keep it short but.

1. Will copy the model definition to a new model so you essentially have the same thing as if you copied the code including extensions from other dependencies loaded before inheriting the model.
2. Will just extend the model adding new functions, will essentially share data but can be avoided by adding a type and correctly filtering models. For example you'd want a type on events to keep them separated logically while keeping them in the same table. This has the advantage to keep things together. So if you want to display multiple types of events in a calendar it will be possible.
3. This will create a new table having some of the data kept in a different table and new data inside the new model table. In other words when you create this new model, you'll create this model and the one being delegated. One example is having an Event and having an Holiday. The holiday type would remain in its table and you could list all holidays, but each holiday would be link to an event with a date and so on. It's a bit like inheritance method 2 with a type except that data is being isolated in different tables.  For example, the holidays will be visible inside the calendar event.event but won't display anything defined in event.holiday as event.event has no idea what's an event.holiday. (for example, res.users -> res.partner is using this method).

With that said, method 2 doesn't really have any cost to implement in speed, method 1 will also be fast as data is kept in its own table but if a module extend the model and isn't in your dependency tree, the changes made to the model won't be visible so it's not 100% copying the schema.

Method 3 is good when you want to keep data normalized where each table own the data it needs to exist and the whole data of the model can be spanned across multiple tables with an implicit one2one relationship.

### Also inheritance of views

Also, you can inherit views to create a new views by setting primary=True.

[Documentation on views](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/views.html#inheritance)

> View matching
>
> - if a view is requested by (model, type), the view with the right model and type, mode=primary and the lowest priority is matched
> - when a view is requested by id, if its mode is not primary its closest parent with mode primary is matched

Setting a view as primary essentially tell odoo to consider it as a top view so it doesn't extend the view it inherits but create a new view with the extension. This can be used with new models being created to prevent custom changes to affect the views of models that don't have the extension.

You can change the model of the view to handle a different model. For example, the holiday model could be handled by inheriting the event.event view and setting the model as event.holiday and changing the type of the view to primary=True. Any other module extending this new view will not have any effect on the parent event.event views.

## Why not copying a whole module:

Now as to why copying an existing module is a bad idea. When you copy a module, you're taking the maintenance of the code on yourself. So any changes from one version to an other or bug fixed in the event module will not be present in your module unless you manually maintain change of code in the event module into your one.

Then you may think it's fine and can get away with it but the moment you'll want to upgrade from let say odoo12 to odoo13. Your module will have to be ported and if you want to rollback your change to create a module that extends the event module like explained above. You'll have to remember exactly which commit you forked the module from. Otherwise you'll have a hard time making a diff and seeing what changes you did introduce and how to port it to odoo13. If you only create a module that extends events, you'll have to port your changes and if you're lucky, you won't have to change anything as since odoo8-10 things didn't change much in some modules so moving from one to an other version is usually straight forward but if you copy you're adding a lot of work in the future for nothing.

Also, this is all based on personal experience after I had to work on projects and modules developed from outsourced companies. Some of the people "developing" the modules did exactly what you're trying to achieve and it costed us so much time to extract the changes made by this company to the PointOfSale which resulted in a module with a few lines of code. The module prevented us from installing the actual point of sale, and the module I had to fix was based from a very old version of the PoS missing critical bug fixes.

It simply isn't worth it.

Comment: Won't setting it as a dependency make it share data?  We already have items in our EVENT module.  I want new data with a different purpose

Comment: Making it as a dependency doesn't make it inherently share data and sometimes sharing data is more or less what you want anyway. Check the ORM inheritance model for more informations.